# .xcodeproj file within .xcworkspace created through cocoa pods is disabled

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I look through the internet I didn't find the answer so here is the problem

I had a project that I used cocoa pods in it and so open it through workspace file that cocoa pods created for me, but after update my os (clean install) to MacOS Sierra the .xcodeproj file is disabled when I open the project within .xcworkspace and every file underneath is not showing,  I had many files grouped into Xcode folders under .xcodeproj file

[image: here is the picture of my Xcode with .xcodeproj file is disable]

Comment: I really stuck into this obstacle please help me if you know anything about this issue

Comment: I delete pods manually and install them again the problem solved but the files did not come back half of the project is gone